# How to get simple freemarker if statement match some string

Tags: freemarker

I have the following freemarker code

```
<#assign carsPriceDescriptionSB = "Price guide" >
<#if vehicle.getPriceDescription == carsPriceDescriptionSB >
<div class="cgl304 data-source small">Some text

<br/><br/>
</div>
</#if>
```

What I want to do is check that the value of **vehicle.getPriceDescription()** is equal to **Price guide** and if the result is true display the block of code

Answer (score 1):

To access the get method you should drop the 'get' or explicitly specify the method name followed by brackets. Avoid using the second method unless necessary.

Normally omit the get prefix

```
<#assign carsPriceDescriptionSB = "Price guide" >
<#if vehicle.priceDescription == carsPriceDescriptionSB >
    <div class="cgl304 data-source small">Some text

    <br/><br/>
    </div>
</#if>
```

Or if it is not a get method then specify the entire method name

```
<#assign carsPriceDescriptionSB = "Price guide" >
<#if vehicle.readPriceDescription() == carsPriceDescriptionSB >
    <div class="cgl304 data-source small">Some text

    <br/><br/>
    </div>
</#if>
```